# ProgressBar with EditText

Tags: java, android

I'm making a search box. when user types down something in here, I'll show suggestions which take a bit amount of time. Considering the buffering, I'd like to show progressbar for users.

To make this feature, I made AsyncTask to show up progressbar and TextWatcher of search box to execute async task.

The problem is that simply, progressbar doesn't show up. As far as I guess, this is probably because TextWatcher doesn't update UI. 
Is there any solution to help me out?

Below is the code I've made. 
Any suggestions will do. Thanks.

```
mSearchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            mProcessTask = new ProgressTask();
            mProcessTask.execute();
            "do something taking time here"
            }
```

And below is the code for AsyncTask

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the possible solution. 
The code attached in the question starts working properly when I changed full screen mode to no titlebar mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
mSearchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Why dont you use the progressbar in the textwatcher itself ...